# Why does the lowest order of soft modes momentum contributes to the action the most here?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, propagator

While reading Altland and Simons CMFT p259-260. I came across with the following problem:

Consider the general structure of the soft mode (Goldstones modes) action $S[\phi] = \sum_{q,i} \phi_q [c_1^i |q_i| + c_2^i q_i^2 ] \phi_{-q} + \mathcal{O} (\phi^4,q^3)$.

The author then claims that the for small q, the green function G(q) scales like $|q|^{-n}$, where n denotes the index of the first non-vanishing coefficient $c_1, c_2, ..., $i.e. the propagation is dominated by the smallest q-power appearing in the action.

My question is that, isn’t it the other way around? I mean the propagator is dominated by the largest power of q, since q is a small number?

It may not be an important question in itself, but I am afraid that I am missing something important here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soft modes will be the one contributing the most at long distance, since gapped modes do not contribute beyond their correlation length / mass.

Now, long distances means low momenta (compared to some unspecified length scale). Then if $q$ is small, then $q^2$ is smaller, and so on. Therefore it is the smallest power that dominates the long-distance behavior of the Green function.

Comment: But the green function is inversely proportional to the moment, i.e. the smaller the momentum is, the larger the green function is.

Comment: How is that a problem ?

Comment: Alright I got it...thought in a wrong way, anyway thanks!